# Sorting unordered list containing hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-lists

I've got an unordered list that contains multiple hyperlinks.
The javascript I have for this appears to be sorting everything inbetween the LI which is throwing things off as some of the hyperlinks are to other domains.
Is there anyway it be updated to sort based on the lists title or name?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sortListDir() {
      var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
      list = document.getElementById("id01");
      switching = true;
      // Set the sorting direction to ascending:
      dir = "asc";
      // Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
      while (switching) {
        // Start by saying: no switching is done:
        switching = false;
        b = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");
        // Loop through all list-items:
        for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
          // Start by saying there should be no switching:
          shouldSwitch = false;
          /* Check if the next item should switch place with the current item,
          based on the sorting direction (asc or desc): */
          if (dir == "asc") {
            if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              /* If next item is alphabetically lower than current item,
              mark as a switch and break the loop: */
              shouldSwitch = true;
              break;
            }
          } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() < b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
              /* If next item is alphabetically higher than current item,
              mark as a switch and break the loop: */
              shouldSwitch= true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {
          /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
          and mark that a switch has been done: */
          b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
          switching = true;
          // Each time a switch is done, increase switchcount by 1:
          switchcount ++;
        } else {
          /* If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
          set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again. */
          if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
            dir = "desc";
            switching = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

My list is currently very simple. Example:

```
<ul id="id01">
   <li><a href="####">Something</a></li>
   <li><a href="####">Something</a></li>
   <li><a href="####">Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So you want to alphabetically sort the list?

Comment: What have you tried so far  to edit your current source code?

Comment: Yes - alphabetically sort the list. I've tried to update the script to look at the 'A' element but ran into the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is simpler to sort array of elements using `Array#sort()` then loop through them sorted and append back to the list

```js
function sortList(dir) {
  var list = document.querySelector('#id01')
  var items = Array.from(list.childNodes).sort(function(a, b) {
    var aTxt = a.textContent.trim(),
      bTxt = b.textContent.trim(),
      ref = dir === 'desc' ? bTxt : aTxt,
      comp = dir === 'desc' ? aTxt : bTxt;
    return ref.localeCompare(comp)
  });
  items.forEach(function(el) {
    list.appendChild(el)
  });
}

// sort buttons for demo
['asc', 'desc'].forEach(function(dir) {
  document.querySelector('#' + dir).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    sortList(dir)
  })
})
```

```html
<button id="asc">Sort Asc</button><button id="desc">Sort desc</button>

<ul id="id01">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works beautifully!! Thank you! Instead of a button to sort how can I have the sort on page load?

Comment: Just call the function inside a load event handler